# Why does journalctl --disk-usage not show the real log disk usage?

Tags: linux, systemd-journald

when I am using this command to see the journal log size of CentOS 7:

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

the output looks like this:

```
[root@k8smasterone log]# journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 48.0M on disk.
```

but the `/var/log/messages` file has a size of more than 4 GB, why does `journalctl` not show the same size of the log? The messages should be treated as journal log.

Comment: *The messages should be treated as journal log* - why? ;-) journald works with `/var/log/journal` **exclusively**. Other files and directories under `/var/log` aren't its concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) only concerns itself with the systemd journal, normally stored in `/run/log/journal` and `/var/log/journal`.

Other files in `/var/log` aren’t part of the systemd journal and aren’t counted by `journalctl --disk-usage`.